# Availability of AWS Cognito in US West (Oregon) region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I found out that AWS Cognito is available in next 3 regions:

- US East (N. Virginia)
- EU (Ireland)
- Asia Pacific (Tokyo)

But I suppose to keep application in US West (Oregon) - so what can I do:

- Wait release of Cognito User Pool in my region?
- Use Cognito from different region (in this scenario I'm affraid that latency of checking `accessToken` in Cognito in different region will be to high)?

Answer (score 0):

Cognito User Pools is actually only currently available in US East during the public beta, but we have heard the request for more regions from multiple customers and will prioritize it accordingly. Cognito Federated Identities is available in the three regions you listed.

Depending on the urgency of the decision, one way to go might be to test a few requests from your location to US East and see what the latency is like. The added overhead shouldn't be prohibitive, I would think.